Copying files (cp and rsync) from rom MacOS formatted exFat sytematically crashes entire system (Ubuntu LTS 24.04)
I am in the process of switching from MacOS (MacBook Pro, Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015, 16GB RAM) to Linux. I installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS about 10 days ago. Copying files (using both rsync and cp) from MacOS formatted exFat systematically crashes entire system (Ubuntu LTS 24.04) 1-2 minutes after launching to the point where I had to hard reboot the computer by pressing the power button. I have reasons to believe that tracker or tracker-miner-f could be the culprit as this was the last command executed (with an error ) just before the crash documented in /var/log/syslog
What has PROBABLY been excluded so far:



tracker-miner-f: crash persisted after removing tracker




It seems to not be a hardware hard drive related problem as the crash occured while transferring same data from 2 different hard drives as source (both formated in exFat).




It seems not to be an rsync specific issue as using cp instead of rsync to transfer data also crashed




It seems not to be a RAM issue (as the RAM and Swap usage was relatively low on crash)




RAM problem on source (MacOS): MemTest successfully run: did not detect any error



What could it be ??:

exFat related formatting problem?
corrupt file

Next steps (being done or to be done):

eleminate the corrupt file
ANY OTHER IDEAS (Please...)???

System
Here are some data regarding my system:
OS: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS x86_64
Host: ThinkPad P1 Gen 6
Kernel: 6.8.0-31-generic
Shell: zsh 5.9
Resolution: 2560x1440
DE: GNOME 46.0
Terminal: tmux
CPU: 13th Gen Intel i7-13700H (20) @ 4.800GHz
GPU: Intel Raptor Lake-P [UHD Graphics]
GPU: NVIDIA RTX 2000 Ada Generation Laptop GPU
Memory: 4211MiB / 31753MiB

Data to be transferred
The data flow is the following I saved with rsync 800GB of data from MacOS (MacBook Pro, Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) to an external hard drive formated in exFat on the exFat. I then tried to save back a subset of the data (70 GB) from the external hard drive to the Linux/Lenovo/Ubuntu 24.04 system described above with the rsync 3.2.7
Here are some data about the 70GB directory that I want to backup. It has approximately 411567 directories and files (using tree subdir > out and counting the line of out. This directory is containing many picture and code (it countains notes and exercices for image recognition deep learning algorithm.)
DETAILED DESCRIPTION OF SEVERAL EXCLUDED CAUSE
1. Probably not tracker related because
Here is a copy of the last 5 minutes before a crash of /var/log/syslog:
2024-05-10T12:54:54.572824+02:00 mylenovo-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-6 tracker-miner-f[3698]: message repeated 8 times: [ Could not execute sparql: Constraint would be broken: UNIQUE constraint failed: rdfs:Resource.ID]
2024-05-10T12:55:01.399803+02:00 mylenovo-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-6 CRON[5519]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
2024-05-10T12:55:03.177883+02:00 mylenovo-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-6 tracker-miner-f[3698]: Could not execute sparql: Constraint would be broken: UNIQUE constraint failed: rdfs:Resource.ID
2024-05-10T12:55:11.905705+02:00 mylenovo-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-6 tracker-miner-f[3698]: Could not execute sparql: Constraint would be broken: UNIQUE constraint failed: rdfs:Resource.ID
2024-05-10T12:55:19.189509+02:00 mylenovo-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-6 rtkit-daemon[1898]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
2024-05-10T12:55:19.189597+02:00 mylenovo-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-6 rtkit-daemon[1898]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
2024-05-10T12:55:20.730061+02:00 mylenovo-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-6 tracker-miner-f[3698]: Could not execute sparql: Constraint would be broken: UNIQUE constraint failed: rdfs:Resource.ID


what I can see maybe of interest is that there are several instances of the following error:
[timestap] mylenovo-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-6 tracker-miner-f[3778]: Could not execute sparql: Constraint would be broken: UNIQUE constraint failed: rdfs:Resource.ID


This is also the last message (with error) recorded on at least 3 different crashes.
I saw the following question related to tracker-miner
tracker-store and tracker-miner-fs eating up my CPU on every startup
and tried the following command:
systemctl --user mask tracker-store.service tracker-miner-fs.service tracker-miner-rss.service tracker-extract.service tracker-miner-apps.service tracker-writeback.service
tracker reset --hard

but got zsh: command not found: tracker. So I tried
tracker3 reset -s
tracker3 reset -r
tracker3 reset -f

and rebooted, rerun a copy script, still crashed but tracker was still on in /var/sys/syslog
Finally I removed tracker with
sudo apt-get remove --purge tracker

the crashes persisted
2. Probably not hardware / Hard drive related because:
I made 2 backups of file on 2 different hard-drives but the crash occur on both hard-drives. So it seems not to be related to hard-drive
3. Probably not cp/rsync related because:
Here is the first script I used script.zsh (with same flags copied from my MacOS machine):
#!/bin/zsh

set -o errexit
set -o nounset
set -o pipefail

VOLUME_NAME="bckp_11"
SUBDIR="subdir"
SOURCEDIR="/media/mycomputer/${VOLUME_NAME}/path/to/Documents/${SUBDIR}"
TARGETDIRCURRENT="/home/mycomputer/Documents/macos_documents/${SUBDIR}"

rsync -vaP $SOURCEDIR $TARGETDIRCURRENT --delete || exit 1

Following comments changed the rsync command several times by changing/removing flags. Here are the following command which I ran which also crashed:
This one crashed:
rsync -vvvvv -a --progress --delete "${SOURCEDIR}" "${TARGETDIRCURRENT}" || exit 1


This one also crashed:
rsync -rptgo --progress --delete "${SOURCEDIR}" "${TARGETDIRCURRENT}" || exit 1

This one also crashed:
setopt +o nullglob; for source in "${SOURCEDIR}"/{,.}*; do rsync -a --progress --delete "${source}" "${TARGETDIRCURRENT}"; done

This one also crashed (where the --delete option was deleted) :
setopt +o nullglob; for source in "${SOURCEDIR}"/{,.}*; do rsync -a --progress "${source}" "${TARGETDIRCURRENT}"; done

I ran sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade and re-run the script setopt +o nullglob; for source in "${SOURCEDIR}"/{,.}*; do rsync -a --progress "${source}" "${TARGETDIRCURRENT}"; done but it still crashed again
I also tried cp instead of sync with the following script, but it also crashed so it does not seem related to rsync
#!/bin/zsh

set -o errexit
set -o nounset
set -o pipefail

VOLUME_NAME="bckp_10"
SUBDIR="ML"

SOURCEDIR="/media/mylenovo/${VOLUME_NAME}/daily_bckp/Users/mymac/Documents/${SUBDIR}"
TARGETDIRCURRENT="/home/mylenovo/Documents/macos_documents/${SUBDIR}"
cp -r $SOURCEDIR $TARGETDIRCURRENT  || exit 1

4. Probably not RAM related on the Linux system because:
I re-ran the commands with htop: when it crashed the MEM bar was visually half full with last bars in yellow, but it said 3.10G/31.06 on the side. The Swp bar was empty with 0K/8.00G (I have 8GB of swap). I conclude that this is not a memory issue, if I am not mistaken (please tell me if you think otherwise)
Some other information in the tmux top pane was the following:
MiB Mem : 31753.9 total, 7666.2 free, 3451.9 used, 21720.0 buff/cache
MiB Swap:  8192.0 total, 8191.7 free,    0.2 used, 28302.0 avail Mem


VIRT     RES     SHR     %CPU   %MEM   COMMAND
989432   178452  20400   109.3  0.5    tracker-miner-f
2359116  75988   11680   50.2   0.2    DisplayLinkMana
19960    5616    3360    16.3   0.0    tmux: server
981060   98276   52084   10.3   0.3    alacritty
18516    8960    6080     9.3   0.0    rsync
5930600  325752  133912   4.7   1.0    gnome-shell
23108    7116    1280     4.3   0.0    rsync
27.3g    154892  103332   3.7   0.5    Xorg

5. Probably not RAM related on the MacOS system because:
I also ran an memtest (PassMark MemTest86 v10.7 https://www.memtest86.com/) on the MacOS system without problem

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Switching from Ubuntu LTS 24.04 to 22.04 solved the problem (without being able to explain in more details why)

Consider filing a launchpad bug report (see the man pages for ubuntu-bug).
